# Change the value of a previously-defined constant

Tags: php, constants

I have defined a constant in PHP e.g.

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value');
```

I want to be able to change the value of this constant later on in the code.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php (emphasis is mine):

> `define` — Defines a named **constant**

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php:

> As the name suggests, that value cannot change during the execution of the script

Comment: Thanks, I realise that now. I had been using define for some 'constants' and thought I could use them. I have used 'global $variable_name' instead.

Answer (score 19):

It is possible to redeclare define, when it was previously defined as case_insensitive constant (3rd parameter).

See:

```
$ php -r "define('TEST','foo',true); var_dump(TEST); define('TEST','bar'); var_dump(TEST);"
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "bar"
```

Tested with PHP CLI 5.2.6 and 5.5.3.

Comment: case_insensitive has been deprecated and will be removed in version 8.0.0.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: This is deprecated as of PHP 7.3

Answer (score 8):

You didnt create a variable, you created a constant. The point of a constant is, that they cannot be changed.

You should use a true variable instead.

Answer (score 4):

Just for work around, passing 3rd param as true will help you

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value', true);
print CONSTANT_NAME.PHP_EOL;
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value2');
print CONSTANT_NAME.PHP_EOL;
```

https://ideone.com/oUG5M9

Comment: This is deprecated as of PHP 7.3

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with **use const ... as ...**:

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value');
define('NEW_CONSTANT_NAME', 'constant_value2');
use const NEW_CONSTANT_NAME as CONSTANT_NAME;
echo CONSTANT_NAME;
```

Comment: Tried but does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a way to change previously defined constants. You have to enable the PHP runkit extension for this purpose: http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php

> The runkit extension provides means to modify constants, user-defined
>   functions, and user-defined classes. It also provides for custom
>   superglobal variables and embeddable sub-interpreters via sandboxing.

It gives you the power to modify whatever aspect you want to modify within PHP. This is advanced stuff though.

Please note that *there is usually a reason for constants to be defined as constants therefore changing this for other purposes than testing is probably not a good idea in almost any case*.