# How to change global variable dynamically inside a function with foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to make a function that change the value of global variable dynamically with a loop.
i tried to to put 'global' behind the $$key but it throws error.
is it possible to do that?

```
define('INPUT_FIELDS', array('fullname', 'phone', 'email')); // the input fields names that every form must have

$fullname = $phone = $email = "";

function isPostValid(){
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if( in_array($key, INPUT_FIELDS) ){// only if the key is exists in the inputs we chose
                $$key = checkInputsAndValidate($key);

                if(!$$key){// if the variable is null then break the loop and make change the variable to false
                    return false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//END foreach
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer help you? [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481869/change-the-value-of-a-previously-defined-constant)

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of the `&$key` syntax for referenced variables? If not then you would need to use `global $key;` as you enter your function to "expose" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dave said in the comment, you have to use the `global` keyword to reference a global variable. But you should also try to make your code scalable for more possible variables (i.e. use an array).

I would suggest to change the function something like this:

```
<?php

define('INPUT_FIELDS', array('fullname', 'phone', 'email'));

/** create a global var that holds all form data **/
$FORM = array();
/** initialize $FORM based on defined input fields **/
foreach (INPUT_FIELDS as $key)
    $FORM[$key] = false;

function isPostValid(){
    /** access global variable $FORM **/
    global $FORM;

    /** verify POST request **/
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST')
        return false;

    /** check all FORM keys for POST values **/
    foreach($FORM as $key => $init_value) {

        /** How does checkInputsAndValidate() work in your code?
          * -> change here if necessary
          **/
        $new_value = isset($_POST[$key]) ? checkInputsAndValidate($key) : false;

        if (!$new_value)
            return false;

        $FORM[$key] = $new_value;
    }

    /** if all is OK, return true **/
    return true;

}

?>
```